# Cakephp isn't show debug messages

Tags: php, debugging, cakephp

I have had some trouble with saving my data.
To know whats wrong I wanted to use `debug($var)` or `debug($this->myModel->validationErrors);` in my controller, but it doesn't seem to give any response.

My situation is posting some data to the same page and saving the data

```
     //my controller
    if ($this->request->is('post')){
        debug($this->request->data);
      //here everything breaks with the message "Error: An Internal Error Has Occurred."
      if($this->Invoice->save($this->request->data)){
            $this->Session->setFlash('Good job, invoice is saved');
        }
     debug($this->Invoice->validationErrors);

    }
```

On the view end I don't have any echo's to show the debugs, because I haven't found sources that did do this.

Comment: Put Configure::write('debug', 2); in your controller and try. Let me know if it still doesn't work.

Comment: @amarjeetkumar inside the action function ?

Comment: Yes, you can put above if ($this->request->is('post')) line

Comment: @amarjeetkumar that worked! I Have no idea why because it was already set to that setting in the core.php. I have checked it a thousand times, because every single answer keeps coming back on that.

Comment: I know the reason. Somewhere in your code this must be set to 0 like Configure::write('debug', 0);. It may be in app_controller or anywhere because of this it was not working in your controller. Now what you are doing is, setting 1 to debug in you controller and its working

Comment: Should I add this in answer here so that others can get help?

Comment: @amarjeetkumar yes you should.

Comment: I have submitted my answer, mark it as correct answer so that others will get help in future. Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Somewhere in your code there must be debug mode set to 0 for example :-

`Configure::write('debug', 0);`.

It may be in app_controller or anywhere because of this it will not work in your controller.

Try setting `Configure::write('debug', 1);` in your controller to avail this feature.

```
  debug($this->Invoice->validationErrors);
```

Comment: Aah thanks for the extra explanation. I understand now

Answer (score 2):

Use cakephp debugkit plugin

https://github.com/cakephp/debug_kit

also you can configure using

```
Configure::write('debug', 2);
```

Try to print output using

```
debug($data);
pr($data);
```

Answer (score 0):

Set the debug level to 2 in the Core.php file

`Configure::write('debug', 2);`

Alternatively modify the db connection to ensure that encoding is enabled, as its commented out by default

```
public $default = array(
    'datasource' => 'Database/Mysql',
    'persistent' => false,
    'host' => 'localhost',
    'login' => 'root',
    'password' => 'password',
    'database' => 'test',
    'prefix' => '',
    'encoding' => 'utf8',
);
```

Comment: Unfortunately it is already set to 2. So that wasn't the problem. Thanks anyways.

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
debug($this->request->data); die();
```